# PostgreSQL how to generate a partition row_number() with certain numbers overridden

Tags: postgresql, row-number

I have an unusual problem I'm trying to solve with SQL where I need to generate sequential numbers for partitioned rows but override specific numbers with values from the data, while not breaking the sequence (unless the override causes a number to be used greater than the number of rows present).

I feel I might be able to achieve this by selecting the rows where I need to override the generated sequence value and the rows I don't need to override the value, then `union`ing them together and somehow using `coalesce` to get the desired dynamically generated sequence value, or maybe there's some way I can utilise `recursive`.

I've not been able to solve this problem yet, but I've put together a SQL Fiddle which provides a simplified version:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/236b5/5

The `desired_dynamic_number` is what I'm trying to generate and the `generated_dynamic_number` is my current work-in-progress attempt.

Any pointers around the best way to achieve the `desired_dynamic_number` values dynamically?

**Update:**

I'm almost there using `lag`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/236b5/24

Comment: What comes after the 999 record? 1000 or 7 or 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=612a06acc956ca088971e372693db29f)

```
SELECT 
    *,
    COALESCE(                                               -- 3
        first_value(override_as_number) OVER w              -- 2
        , 1
    )
    + row_number() OVER w - 1                               -- 4, 5
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(                                                -- 1
            CASE WHEN override_as_number IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) OVER (PARTITION BY grouped_by ORDER BY secondary_order_by)
            as grouped
    FROM sample
) s
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY grouped_by, grouped ORDER BY secondary_order_by)
```

1. Create a new subpartition within your partitions: This cumulative sum creates a unique group id for every group of records which starts with a `override_as_number <> NULL` followed by `NULL` records. So, for instance, your `(AAA, d)` to `(AAA, f)` belongs to the same subpartition/group.
2. `first_value()` gives the first value of such subpartition.
3. The `COALESCE` ensures a non-`NULL` result from the `first_value()` function if your partition starts with a `NULL` record.
4. `row_number() - 1` creates a row count within a subpartition, starting with `0`.
5. Adding the `first_value()` of a subpartition with the row count creates your result: Beginning with the one non-`NULL` record of a subpartition (adding the `0` row count), the first following `NULL` records results in the value +1 and so forth.

Comment: And thanks to you also! Very much appreciated :) I love the explanation you've provided too. Both yours and sqlandplsql's solution seem to provide the correct results, but yours seems easier to follow. And thank you for introducing me to the WINDOW function I was previously unaware of.

Comment: is there a way to remove the reliance on secondary_order_by? If I introduce some randomness there then I get different final numbers. I introduced secondary_order_by simply to keep the desired_dynamic_number in line with the generated_dynamic_number for quick testing of results. Regardless, thank you for introducing me to WINDOW as I should be able to do some grunt work hopefully to figure it out myself... I hope! :P

Comment: You need something to order within your partitions. For instance, you cannot say what is the first value of a partition, if you would not order it (first_value). You need the order as well for the cumulative SUM at the beginning. So removing the secondary order column means to find another criterion to ensure a fixed order inside the partitions.

Comment: In the real world example there is a secondary column I can use, a created timestamp. But when I applied the solution it no longer worked. This can be tested by adding some randomisation to the secondary_order_by column with shuffled values e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=c8c48646e006b864ea92d6275a759675 . The desired_dynamic_number can be ignored in this case, as long as there's sequential numbers at the end and any override_as_number value applied (exactly like the original solution you gave). Played for a day but not figured out a solution myself yet - still playing!

Comment: well, your desired output is not ordered by your secondary column.

Answer (score 1):

Below query gives exact result, but you need to verify with all combinations

```
select c.*,COALESCE(c.override_as_number,c.act) as final FROM
(
select b.*, dense_rank() over(partition by grouped_by order by grouped_by, actual) as act from
(
select a.*,COALESCE(override_as_number,row_num) as actual FROM  
(
select grouped_by , secondary_order_by  ,      
dense_rank() over ( partition by grouped_by order by grouped_by, secondary_order_by ) as row_num                             
,override_as_number,desired_dynamic_number                                                                                   from fiddle    
) a
) b 
) c ;
```

column "final" is the result

```
grouped_by | secondary_order_by | row_num | override_as_number | desired_dynamic_number | actual | act | final 
------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+------------------------+--------+-----+-------
 AAA        | a                  |       1 |                  1 |                      1 |      1 |   1 |     1
 AAA        | b                  |       2 |                    |                      2 |      2 |   2 |     2
 AAA        | c                  |       3 |                  3 |                      3 |      3 |   3 |     3
 AAA        | d                  |       4 |                  3 |                      3 |      3 |   3 |     3
 AAA        | e                  |       5 |                    |                      4 |      5 |   4 |     4
 AAA        | f                  |       6 |                    |                      5 |      6 |   5 |     5
 AAA        | g                  |       7 |                999 |                    999 |    999 |   6 |   999
 XYZ        | a                  |       1 |                    |                      1 |      1 |   1 |     1
 ZZZ        | a                  |       1 |                    |                      1 |      1 |   1 |     1
 ZZZ        | b                  |       2 |                    |                      2 |      2 |   2 |     2
(10 rows)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! :) SQL Fiddle for others convenience - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1f35e/3

Comment: @Gavin I guess, it works not perfectly. See this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=8372cb578e7f19201f23162db9f4ce46 I guess, the TO would expect to keep the `abcde` order, but this query orders the `e` before `d` with a wrong `final` number (first: 3 comes after 5; and second: it should have been 11, as I understood)

Answer (score 0):

The real world problem I was trying to solve did not have a nicely ordered `secondary_order_by` column, instead it would be something a bit more randomised (a created timestamp).

For the benefit of people who stumble across this question with a similar problem to solve, a colleague solved this problem using a cartesian join, who's solution I'm posting below. The solution is Snowflake SQL which should be possible to adapt to Postgres. It does fall down on higher `override_as_number` values though unless the `from table(generator(rowcount => 1000))` 1000 value is not increased to something suitably high.

The SQL:

```
with tally_table as (
    select row_number() over (order by seq4()) as gen_list
    from table(generator(rowcount => 1000))
),
base as (
select *,
    IFF(override_as_number IS NULL, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY grouped_by, override_as_number order by random),override_as_number) as rownum
    from "SANDPIT"."TEST"."SAMPLEDATA" order by grouped_by,override_as_number,random
) --select * from base order by grouped_by,random;
,
cart_product as (
    select *
    from tally_table cross join (Select distinct grouped_by from base ) as distinct_grouped_by
)  --select * from cart_product;
,
filter_product as (
    select *,
    row_number() OVER(partition by cart_product.grouped_by order by cart_product.grouped_by,gen_list) as seq_order
    from cart_product
  where CONCAT(grouped_by,'~',gen_list) NOT IN (select concat(grouped_by,'~',override_as_number) from base where override_as_number is not null)
) --select * from try2 order by 2,3 ;
select base.grouped_by,
    base.random,
    base.override_as_number,
    base.answer,  -- This is hard coded as test data
    IFF(override_as_number is null, gen_list, seq_order) as computed_answer
from base inner join filter_product on base.rownum = filter_product.seq_order and base.grouped_by = filter_product.grouped_by
order by base.grouped_by,
random;
```

In the end I went for a simpler solution using a temporary table and cursor to inject `override_as_number` values and shuffle other numbers.